# Find out inheritance relation between two objects classes in c++

Tags: c++, reflection, inheritance

I've got an abstract C++ base class CPlugin. From it, there are many classes derived directly and indirectly. Now given CPlugin *a,*b I need to find out, if a's real class is derived from b's real class.

I.e. I'd like to do something like this:

```
void checkInheritance(CPlugin *a, CPlugin *b){
  if (getClass(a).isDerivedFrom(getClass(b)){
    std::cout << "a is a specialization from b's class" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But how do I implement the "getClass" and "isDerivedFrom" in C++?

Comment: Generally speaking in C++, a design that requires reflection in this manner needs to be reconsidered. Why do you need to check if one `CPlugin` is derived from another `CPlugin`? I can't see why such information is necessary for the code that uses `CPlugin`.

Comment: The only way is to implement this `getClass` operation (i.e. basic type reflection capability for your types) yourself. This quickly becomes tedious (and dirty) especially if multiple inheritace comes to play... An, yes, as suggested above, if I were you, I'd rather ask myself why do I need to do know that.

Comment: What's the goal that led you to consider a `checkInheritance` function?

Comment: Qt supports this!!!! I've done this exact thing..

Comment: For curiosity's sake, what's the real-life use of this function?

Comment: @ianmac45: Qt supports this by extending the C++ language via their Meta Object Compiler which looks for special macros in the code to be processed. It's not a built-in part of the language.

Comment: @ silico: very insightful. i never knew i was programming in c++ all this time. weird.....

Comment: Simply because if A is derived from B then A is supposed to implements all the methods present in B. This is very useful if you are doing runtime affectations. Imagine you have a list of objects but they are not all the same kind of class. To use them somewhere, you should then do a casting. In order to cast them the right way you would prefer to check if those elements are really implementing the right methods or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in C++. The only way to get some information about types on runtime is RTTI. RTTI is not powerful enough to do what you need though. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, then you will get better answers.

Comment: @Oli possibly because you *can* do this in C++, but like most things, C++ doesn't do this for you, you have to do it yourself. +1 from me though.

Answer (score 3):

A whole solution is really tough to provide. What you are trying to achieve is a behavior that depends on the concrete type of two parameters : this is called double dispatch. A few pages of Modern C++ Design (Andrei Alexandrescu) are devoted to this subjet.

Once the actual concrete type of both parameters are known at a single code point, the "isDerivedFrom" part can be answered using boost type_traits : [boost is_base_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html).

Comment: @icecrime: `is_base_of` is a compile time construct - it doesn't work for arbitrary runtime pointers.

Comment: Absolutely, this is why I think there are two aspects to this problem : achieving double dispatch to get the concrete type of both parameters, and using boost::is_base_of to verify inheritance relationship. I'll edit my answer to clarity this.

Comment: Hoo, you are so fast, where can I complain? :) I am dreaming of the moment, when I make it to publish a first answer or comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the issue with my reasoning. Double dispatch will allow to OP to have a single function/method where the parameters will be passed with their respective CONCRETE type. From this point of the code, I don't see how calling is_base_of is an issue.

Comment: @icecrime: There won't be a single function; there'll have to be one for every single class (or possibly one for every *combination* of classes).

Comment: True, but I'll keep thinking that you downvote is rough as I sincerely believe I provided a viable solution :p

Comment: @icecrime: It's true that this is theoretically viable, so I'll remove the downvote.  However, it's a maintenance nightmare for anything other than a handful of classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic cast to test whether an object belongs to a subtype of a type known at compile time. The mechanism for changing behaviour depending on the runtime type of an object is a virtual function, which gives you a scope where the type of the receiver is known at compile time.

So you can achieve the same effect by a virtual function so you have the type at compile time on one side, and then dynamic cast to check the other side against that type:

```
#include <iostream>

class Plugin {
    public:
    virtual bool objectIsDerivedFromMyClass ( const Plugin & object ) const = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename BasePlugin = Plugin>
class TypedPlugin : public BasePlugin {
    public:
    virtual bool objectIsDerivedFromMyClass ( const Plugin & object ) const {
        return dynamic_cast<const T*> ( &object ) != 0;
    }

    private:
        int CheckMe(const T*) const;
};

class PluginA : public TypedPlugin<PluginA> {};
class PluginB : public TypedPlugin<PluginB, PluginA> {};
class PluginC : public TypedPlugin<PluginC> {};

int main () {
    PluginA a;
    PluginB b;
    PluginC c;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << "type of a is derived from type of a " <<  a.objectIsDerivedFromMyClass ( a ) << '\n'
    << "type of a is derived from type of b " <<  b.objectIsDerivedFromMyClass ( a ) << '\n'
    << "type of b is derived from type of a " <<  a.objectIsDerivedFromMyClass ( b ) << '\n'
    << "type of c is derived from type of a " <<  a.objectIsDerivedFromMyClass ( c ) << '\n'
    ;

    return 0;
}
```

(You also may want to add a check that `T` extends `TypedPlugin<T>`)

It's not quite double dispatch, though `dynamic_cast` is runtime polymorphic on its argument so it is pretty close.

Though for anything much more complicated (or if you want to stick with your original style of comparing the objects which represent the runtime types of the objects you have), you need to start create  metaclasses, or use an existing framework which supplies metaclasses. Since you're talking about plugins, you may already have somewhere to specify configuration properties or dependencies, and that could be used for this too.

Answer (score 0):

Typeinfo and dynamic cast: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/

Comment: This doesn't allow one to determine whether the runtime class of `*b` derives from the runtime class of `*a`.

Comment: Dynamic cast does allow you to determine that @Oli

Comment: dynamic_cast returns null or throws an exception if the two classes aren't compatible. It doesn't actually tell you which is the parent and which is the child, but if you know which is the base class then you can use dynamic_cast to check if it is a child.

Comment: I may be mistaken, can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @Cisco: The OP doesn't have *classes*, he has *objects*.  Given `CPlugin *a, *b`, you cannot use `dynamic_cast` to do anything useful (as you don't have any compile-time types other than `CPlugin`).

Comment: @Cisco: if I understand you correctly, this would work if the type to be cased into is known at compile time. But how would you determine the type in runtime?

Comment: @Vlad What you can do at runtime is to check the real type of the object (`type_info`). But the type you need to check against (`dynamic_cast` only tests compatibility = child/parent/same) has to be provided during compilation. Now the thing is that anything else then this doesn't make much sense from the code perspective. You can't really do anything with the specific information that something is a child.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are after, but you can always use virtual methods in the following manner:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct TypeChecker
{
  virtual bool ParentOf(CPlugin const& c) const
  {
    return dynamic_cast<Derived const*>(&c);
  }
};
```

Now, augment the `CPlugin` class with the following pure virtual method:

```
  virtual bool ParentOf(CPlugin const& c) const = 0;
```

And make each class deriving from `CPlugin` inherit from `TypeChecker` as well:

```
class SomePlugin: public CPlugin, private TypeChecker<SomePlugin> {};
```

And finally use it like such:

```
void checkInheritance(CPlugin const& lhs, CPlugin const& rhs)
{
  if (!rhs.ParentOf(lhs)) return;

  std::cout << "lhs is derived from rhs' class\n";
}
```

This does not detect if it is a specialization though, since both could perfectly be of the exact same class, this can be detected by using the `typeid` operator.

Note the requirement to implement it for every single class deriving from `CPlugin` and you'll understand why it is so complicated and error-prone...